# Riddle with a fang

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> My head is grey and I guess my tail is too
>
> I'm straight as a pencil if brand new
>
> If used correctly my fang should disappear
>
> Only to leave my head shown clear
>
> Looking around I'm not usually seen
>
> And this math equation can be true if done by me
>
> 1+1=1

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> A nail

Seeing that:

> Nail heads are grey, as are the shaft. Nails can't really see so it only can guess. They are straight when new, head left showing on surface with the pointed "fang" disappearing. They are everywhere but not often seen. As for the 1+1=1:  by nailing two things together they become one (Thanks to Dan in the comments for the hint on that part).

Comment: Hi Brandon, welcome to puzzling! Your answer should address all clues given by the OP, including the first line `My head is grey and I guess my tail is too`.

Comment: Maybe the equation part is about combining two separate things to make one new thing.

Comment: Very nice, I like that you touched up on all the lines ( ;