# I can make 1 + 1 = 1. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I begin with the last.
>
> I can make 1 + 1 = 1.
>
> If you miss me, then I will make you shy.
>
> My other side can be used as identification.
>
> I can make things smaller.
>
> Sometimes I can upset you.

Can you guess me what am I?

Comment: See also [Riddle with a fang](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42322/riddle-with-a-fang), which is probably utterly unrelated :-)

Comment: @rand al;thor Answer is different..

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. Interesting how the same line can be used in two different riddles to mean two entirely different things (and can [inspire people to create new kinds of puzzles](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/5533/5373))!

Comment: I think I may have the answer, but I'm having trouble making it fit with the 3rd, (4th), and 6th lines.

Comment: @rand al'thor   please post partial answer...

Comment: I came judging only by the title. Was armed with the following: *Define a+b := max(a,b). Then 1+1 = max(1,1)=1. And hence you are the binary operation +*. Too bad it had more stuff. :/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you

> ZIP

I begin with the last.

> First letter is 'Z', the last letter of the alphabet.

I can make 1 + 1 = 1.

> This is more or less what any fastening device does. In this case, examples could be a zipper, a .zip file, or the python zip function.

If you miss me, then I will make you shy.

> If you forget to 'zip' your pants, you might become embarrassed.

My other side can be used as identification.

> Zip codes

I can make things smaller.

> File compression via .zip

Sometimes I can upset you.

> Nothing solid for this one...

Comment: A zip can upset if it does not work.

Comment: "identification" = zip code?

Comment: The expression "zip it" can upset people? http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/zip-it

Comment: @randal'thor I thought about that, but why the 'other side' then?

Comment: "[blank] can make someone sad/angry" can basically be filled in by anything. Im assuming there's a clever answer, possibly using a more subtle meaning of upset.

Comment: @kayzeroshot  Congrats!!! you are correct..upvote for you..

Comment: other side means, other meaning..

Comment: As rand al'thor mentioned, it is a zip code..

Comment: You'll get upset if you zip without looking.

Comment: I often get irritated at zippers; if they malfunction it's a pain to get them working again

Comment: @kayzeroshort "Sometimes I upset you" See There's Something About Mary

Answer (score 15):

Took me a minute, but you are definitely

> A pair of shoes

I begin with the last.

> A pair of shoes can be made with a last -- Credit to @h34

I can make 1 + 1 = 1.

> 1 shoe + 1 shoe = 1 pair of shoes

If you miss me, then I will make you shy.

> If you forget your shoes you will be shy

My other side can be used as identification.

> footprints are used in investigations

I can make things smaller.

> Stepping on things can make them smaller. Also the fact that they make you taller can make other things smaller.

Sometimes I can upset you.

> Tripping on shoelaces can aggravate you.

Comment: The making of shoes can begin using a [last](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last).

Comment: @h34 Thanks, you strengthened my weakest point. I'm now pretty sure I got this right! Credited you in main post.

Comment: Nice..upvote for you..

Comment: Why would forgetting ones shoes make one "shy"? And you step on things with your feet, regardless of whether you are wearing shoes. Finally, avoid the word "definitely"... ;)

Answer (score 11):

As requested by the OP, I'm posting this as an answer even though my explanations for the third and fourth lines are quite shaky.

> ZERO.

*I begin with the last.*

> The word "zero" begins with the last letter of the alphabet, Z.

*I can make 1 + 1 = 1.*

> In binary, $1+1=10$ - the addition of a zero makes the equation 1+1=1 true.

*If you miss me, then I will make you shy.*

> Missing a zero when writing down a large number could be a big blunder (potentially putting you out by a factor of 10), which might make you shy. *(Thanks to @Sid for help with this line - it's shaky, but still better than just "not sure", which is what I had before.)*

*My other side can be used as identification.*

> The best explanation I can come up with for this line (and it's very shaky) is that ZERO backwards is OREZ, and ores might be used in identifying metal deposits.

*I can make things smaller.*

> Adding extra zeros to a number like $0.1$, to turn it into $0.01$ or $0.0001$, does indeed make it smaller.

*Sometimes I can upset you.*

> Having zero of something can be upsetting? Or, better, getting a mark of zero in a text or exam can certainly be upsetting (thanks @Pere).

Comment: For the third line, Probably missing a zero from, say, 1,000,000? It would be a huge blunder?

Comment: @Sid Shaky, but less so than my explanation for the fourth line. Added - thanks :-)

Comment: @rand al'thor  you tried well, some statements matched. But it is not the answer. Upvote for well tried..

Comment: @Sathi Is it a word beginning with Z, or have I interpreted the first line completely wrong? (or don't you want to say yet?)

Comment: @rand al'thor  Your first line 100% correct...but it is not Zero

Comment: `+`  could also mean binary or, in which `1 + 1 <=> 1 or 1 = 1`

Comment: About a zero upsetting you, in countries where marks are given as numbers, the usual scale is 0-10 (instead of A-E) with 0 being the worst possible mark. A zero mark is likely to upset students - at least those to expected to pass.

Comment: Furthermore, Zeros can upset people in more serious way. For example, in December 7th 1941 American people got extremely upset by some Zeros ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitsubishi_A6M_Zero ) at Pearl Harbour.

Answer (score 10):

I begin with the last.

> mirror - reverses things front to back

I can make 1 + 1 = 1.

> mirror - raid mirroring makes two copies one. two mirror copies are actually 1.

If you miss me, then I will make you shy.

> mirror - if you forget to look at yourself in the mirror, you might go around being shy.

My other side can be used as identification.

> mirror - recognize yourself.

I can make things smaller.

> mirror - rear-view mirror.

Sometimes I can upset you.

> mirror - don't like the way you look.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Could you edit this answer to add in an explanation as to why you think it is correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I am a

> mistake or an error

I begin with the last.

> While correcting errors/mistakes people begin by seeing the end results and then working downwards towards the root.

I can make 1 + 1 = 1.

> It's a mistake.

If you miss me, then I will make you shy.

> Silly mistakes/goof ups can make people shy.

My other side can be used as identification.

> Mistakes can be used to identify the qualities, state of mind of the person who made them.

I can make things smaller.

> It can reduce a person's ego, numerically smaller etc

Sometimes I can upset you.

> Quite obvious :)

Comment: Well tried........